# how to git clone via https with personal access token in private project gitlab

Tags: authentication, cmd, gitlab

I want to git clone a private repository with two factor authentication on my mac, I already have a personal access token in my gitlab, and I'm trying to find the correct command to run on the vscode terminal.

omarfuentes@192 ~ % git clone https://gitlab.com/OmarLeonardo/frappe/proyectos/frappe-oms/frappe-server.git?personal_access_token=myaccesstoken

however the answer is:
zsh: no matches found: https://gitlab.com/OmarLeonardo/frappe/proyectos/frappe-oms/frappe-server.git?personal_access_token=myaccesstoken

Comment: A 'word' (nonblank nondelimiter characters) in shell is assumed to be a possible filename and if it contains an unquoted questionmark `?` or asterisk `*` or sometimes other chars it is treated as a [**'glob' pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) and the shell tried to 'match' it against the names of actual files. Since you have no actual file names like that URL, it fails. **Quote the `?`** -- either put `' '` or `" "` around the URL _or_ relevant part, or put backslash (can't be shown correctly on Stack) immediately before the `?`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a PAT (Personal Access Token) with [the right scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#personal-access-token-scopes), you should use:

```
git clone https://<my-user-id>:<my-token>@gitlab.com/<my-account>/<my-project-name>.git
# or
git clone https://oauth2:<my-token>@gitlab.com/<my-account>/<my-project-name>.git
```

That would avoid the need to URL encode your parameter.

But to avoid exposing the token directly in the remote URL, consider using a [credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

Comment: thank you for answering @VonC and for your help. Can you please clarify what <my-account>really means, because I only know about my <my-user-id>. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @OmarFUENTESRAMOS It is your gitlab account username. Don't include the `<` and `>`: they are just here as a placeholder value marker.

Comment: Worked perfectly. If you are using `github`, just replace `gitlab` with `github`

Comment: Note that this exposes our PAT by running `git remote -v` you can see creds in plain text.

Comment: @Ari True. I have amended the answer to include a credential storage recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, if you created your account with Google you can find your username in the URL to the repository. You can also see the name of your project there. So if your URL looks like the below:

https://gitlab.com/me1234567/myproject/-/tree/main

your final command would look like this:

git clone https://oauth2:my-personal-token-123@gitlab.com/me1234567/myproject.git

The User ID you see under the Gitlab Edit profile can not be used, nor your email address or the "username" you see under your avatar which starts with @