# Using project access token to clone a private gitlab repository

Tags: git, gitlab, access-token

I have a private repository that is hosted on gitlab.com. I've created a project access token with `read_repository` scope. The intention is that any user with the project access token can clone the repository.

I'm issuing:

```
git clone https://xyz@gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

and when prompted for my password, I enter the project access token, but am told:

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
Password for 'https://xyz@gitlab.com': 
remote: You are not allowed to download code from this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/user/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've tried creating a number of additional project access tokens with multiple scopes in addition to `read_repository`, but get the same error. I've also tried cloning using the project access token directly in the clone:

```
git clone https://xyz:MY_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

but get the same error.

**Clarifications**

All project access tokens I've created have an expiry date set to a month from now. The `xyz` string is, to my understanding, irrelevant, since it's a placeholder for the username. From the gitlab documentation, it seems this can be any non-empty string.

Comment: oauth2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72371417/how-to-git-clone-via-https-with-personal-access-token-in-private-project-gitlab

Comment: What is `xyz`? It should be a generated username or the literal `oauth2`. Did you set expiration date while creating the token? To my experience, some people mistakenly set the expiration date with today, which makes the token expired at once.

Comment: My understanding is that the username part of the command is irrelevant, so it can by `xyz` just as much as `oauth2`. But regardless, I was conscious of this post and have tried using `oauth2` to no effect.

Comment: All the project access tokens that I've used have an expiry date a month from now.

Comment: @KamilCuk Could you provide a reference for this? But regardless, my previous comment stating that I've tried `oauth2` to no effect kind of makes this moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm as [@ton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77118217/3299257) rightly noted, `Reporter` is the minimal level needed for reading repository, despite (or more precise in addition to) the flags set  when creating project access token.

For others facing similar problems, I have discovered following levels needed:

| Operation | Level |
| --- | --- |
| reading (git fetch, git clone etc.) | Reporter |
| writing (git push) | Developer |
| writing to protected branch | Maintainer |

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the issue was that we can not use "Guest" tokens in private repos even with permissions will be 403. Using "Reporter" or any other works

Answer (score 2):

What does the xyz stands for ?
Are you the owner of the repository / do you have permissions ?

--- What you actually want to do is add the oauth2 protocol before the actual token

`git clone https://oauth2:MY_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/user/repo.git`

If it doesnt help, try executing a rest api using this token to make sure it is valid.

Try Referring [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148841/github-clone-with-oauth-access-token?rq=2) for further investigating.

Comment: Good point on the oauth2 token.  Also, you can use any value in the places of `oath2` in that URL, for instance, this works:


`git clone https://hack_the_gibson:MY_ACCESS_TOKEN@gitlab.com/user/repo.git`


A generic URL (for CI) can use CI variables:


`git clone https://gibson:${ACCESS_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.git`